# Is there a name for these especially simple directed acyclic graphs, and are any decent characterizations known?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Define the notion of a "foo digraph" recursively as follows.

- If we take any finite number of directed [path graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PathGraph.html) each of which has at least $2$ vertexes, and glue them at the start and end vertexes, the result is a foo digraph.
- If we take any foo digraph and replace an edge in that digraph with a foo digraph pointing `in the correct direction,' the result is a foo digraph.
- Nothing else is a foo digraph.

For example:

[image]

is a foo digraph, where the arrows implicitly point down.

So basically, we're talking about directed acyclic graphs that equal their own transitive reductions, subject to some constraints saying that certain subgraphs like

[image]

can't appear, and some completeness conditions saying that there's a start vertex $\top$, and end vertex $\bot$, and that each vertex $v$ must correspond to another vertex $v'$ such that the out-degree of $v$ equals the in degree of $v'$, and the set of paths from $\top$ to $\bot$ that pass through $v$ equals the set of paths from $\top$ to $\bot$ that pass through $v'$.

The above may not be a complete characterization.

> **Question.** Is there a name for what I'm calling foo digraphs, and are any decent graph-theoretic characterizations known?

Comment: This is series-parallel graph (which is undirected, but can be uniquely made directed).

Comment: Worth pointing out: **if $D$ is a foo-digraph, then the free category generated by $G$ is a [confluent category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/confluent+category).** I have not looked into the question if and how the converse holds.

Comment: One can probably characterize this as follows: 'a digraph $D$ is a foo-digraph if and only if it is (the downwards orientation of) a **Hasse diagram* of a finite poset with both a greatest and a least element and property $P$', where I am unsure at the moment what the right $P$ is.

Comment: @PeterHeinig: triangles are allowed, I think.

Comment: @MartinRubey: you are right in saying that triangles are allowed by goblin, more precisely, goblin allows one to construct a *transitive tournaments on three vertices*, and $\text{ therefore Hasse diagrams are irrelevant here}$ (please note I only said 'probably'). How to get a transitive triangle from goblin's axioms: start with two copies of a directed path, glued at their endvertices (= 'oriented [dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_graph)' ), then apple goblin's second axiom to replace one of the constituent 2-vertex paths by a 3-vertex directed path.

Comment: One should add that while Yuzhou Gu seems to have exactly identified the class defined by Goblin, this thread is still lacking a precise reference to one of the several definitions of $\mathsf{SeriesParallelGraphs}$ which would make it obvious that goblin's graphs are precisely (orientations of) series-parallel graphs. I can imagine someone working on something, under time pressure, stumbling upon this thread, finding goblin's graphs exactly what they need, seeing 'series-parallel', but noticing that the correspondence with the Wikipedia page is not evident, and missing something verifiable.